# Store multiple groups into collection

Tags: java, collections, nested, grouping

I need to store several entries grouped by a key word into a collection.

- group1

  - entry1
  - entry2
- group2

  - entry3
  - entry4
  - entry5
- group3

  - entry6
  - entry7

So I assume, I need a structure like that

```
[group1[entry1,entry2],group2[entry3,entry4,entry5],group3[entry6,entry7]]
```

Would a nested array be the right choice?

Comment: Does the order of the groups matter? Does the order of the entries within the groups matter?

Comment: @PaulBoddington The order of the groups do matter, the order of the entries would be a nice to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Map`.

A `TreeMap` will order the groups using a `Comparator` or by the natural order of the keys. In this example, the groups will be ordered alphabetically by the name of the group.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("Group1", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Entry1", "Entry2")));
map.put("Group2", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Entry3", "Entry4", "Entry5")));
map.put("Group3", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Entry6", "Entry7")));
System.out.println(map);
```

If you want to get the entries of a particular group you can do

```
List<String> list = map.get("Group2");
```

You may prefer the groups stay in the order you put them in the `Map`. In this case you should use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `TreeMap`.